# I'm switching from an Intel platform to an AMD platform. Do I need to reinstall Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, uefi

I am currently running an Intel 8700k platform, but I plan to switch to an AMD Ryzen 5900X platform, carrying over the same nVidia 2080ti GPU. I know Windows will require a clean installation, but will Ubuntu need the same treatment? In other words, can I just install my current NVMe drive into the new board and keep going as if nothing happened?

I am running Ubuntu Groovy with official ubuntu-repo/apt DKMS nVidia Drivers + Secure Boot.

Bonus question: How can I get DKMS to enroll the existing key into the UEFI of the new board?

Comment: Best practice is a clean install with a significant hardware change.  "Can I?" vs "Should I?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing should need to change as it really depends more on the actual architecture, for example if someone went from 32bit to 64bit (i686 to amd64 if I can remember correctly).

Really good choice of CPU too!

Only thing you need to be careful of is if you're into software or low level programs - Intel has memory addresses written backwards (Little Endian) whereas AMD does it the better way, Big Endian; but if you're just a general user, you needn't worry!

(Enjoy your awesome upgrade!)

Edit seeing as a very angry and short tempered person in the comments pointed out: Your question about the NVMe drive should be fine. You should be absolutely in the clear to put the existing drive in and continue seamlessly.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to do anything. If it is the same GPU, then the driver should work on either Intel or AMD.

But if Secure Boot is involved, you may need to disable it, or resubmit the key to UEFI.